# Is there a way around macports to install libtool?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, libtool

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346424/how-to-update-m4-autoconf-automake-and-libtool-properly-mac-osx), I need to install macports to get libtool and various other dependencies.

Is it possible to do this without macports? Can I download these files individually somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing macports for autotools is not required, since you can build them from source.  It's probably not as convenient, but it works. The [autoconf](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/), [automake](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/), and [libtool](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libtool/) are available from ftp.gnu.org.